# Apple Pay with Woocommerce (Stripe) "Unable to verify domain - Forbidden"

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

Everything is setup and I have `.well-known` folder in my root directory with file.

My Stripe account is activated and my domain is added under Apple Pay tab.

Now when I enable Stripe, I get this notification:

> Apple Pay domain verification failed. Please check the log to see the
>   issue.

When I check the error log, I see:

> Error: Unable to verify domain - Forbidden

My hosting is on [OVH](https://www.ovh.com).

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution and now its working :)
Stripe no longer supports API requests made with TLS 1.0. Please update HTTPS connections with TLS 1.2 or later.

[image]

Hosting server is using TLS older version which is not supported anymore
due to security
The upgrade process will be seamless for most users. At the application layer, SHA-2 and TLS 1.2 behave identically to their older versions. You won’t need to change your code, but might need to upgrade your operating system or packages. 
for ref:https://stripe.com/blog/upgrading-tls

Hope it will help!!

Answer (score 0):

Have you added Domain Verification file into the .well-known/ folder.

If not please find it in your Stripe dashboard download it or [here](http://stripe.com/files/apple-pay/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association) and upload to .well-known/ folder.

Make sure that you need to access your verification file by your URL https://example.com/.well-known/apple-developer-merchantid-domain-association

Comment: See my question i have the file and everything is place ..also i have resolved it see below issue was 
Hosting server is using TLS older version which is not supported anymore due to security The upgrade process will be seamless for most users. At the application layer, SHA-2 and TLS 1.2 behave identically to their older versions. You won’t need to change your code, but might need to upgrade your operating system or packages

Answer (score 0):

In my Case i was using WHMCS on a subdomain, and had to insert the apple merchant file on the root path ./well-known of my domain

```
subdomain.domain.com/.well˜
domain.com/.well˜
```

Solved my problem